# Entity Framework Code First HashSet not generating migration code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

- ASP.NET 4.61, EF 6.1.3
- SQL Server 2012

I have a the following POCO:

```
public class GdataHealthTableModel : AuditedEntity
{
    public GdataHealthTableModel()
    {
        PrevHealthAssessment = new HashSet<HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum>();
    }

    public HashSet<HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum> PrevHealthAssessment { get; set; }
}
```

but this does not generate a migration for the column **PrevHealthAssessment**. So what is the correct construct to be able to store multiple enum members so that EF "understands it" and will generate a migration?

Comment: EF will not create an entity for enums. Why don't you create a class (e.g. `PrevHealthAssessment`) that has the `HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum` as a property and in the `GdataHealthTableModel`, add `HashSet<PrevHealthAssessment>` as a property.

Comment: Ok so that will do the many to one relationship. But I am guessing that I actually then need an ICollection<PrevHealthAssessment> PrevHealthAssessments?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added an answer with the full explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new entity and name it e.g. `PrevHealthAssessment` which will have the `HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum` as a property.

```
public class PrevHealthAssessment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum HealthPrevHealthAssessment { get; set; }

}
```

In `GdataHealthTableModel`, add a collection of the newly created entity like this:

`public ICollection<PrevHealthAssessment> PrevHealthAssessments {get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ICollection type.

```
 public class GdataHealthTableModel : AuditedEntity
 {
   public GdataHealthTableModel()
    {
      PrevHealthAssessment = new HashSet<HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum>();
    }

   public ICollection<HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum> PrevHealthAssessment { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: That solution does not work and generates no migration.